# C# ++ and -- incrementing double var by 0.1

Tags: c#, .net

apologies if this has been asked, but I cannot find it.

I have a double variable which I am doing ++ and -- to increase and decrease the value.

My number is 95.8 for example, and the ++ would make it 96.8

But I would like the ++ operator to increment by 0.1 each time, therefore the number would increase to 95.9 for example.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: why you don't use += operator?

Comment: Don't you think that might confuse others who will expect a different behavior? What's wrong with "myDouble += 0.1;" ?

Comment: BTW, note that incrementing by 0.1 each time could introduce floating-point errors (since 0.1 is not representable as an exact number in binary floating-point). Consider representing the number as an integer, e.g., 958 and 959 in your example, then dividing by 10 upon display.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using double as that is what the control requires to be fed with. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not supported unless you create your own type (class) and override these operators.

Use the following instead:

```
x += 0.1;
```

Comment: I would shamelessly strangle the person who would overload the ++ operator to increment by something other than 1 on a numeric type.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, same here. Especially since there is already syntax to do this in a clear and concise way.

Comment: Perfect Jonathan, I have not used the += operator before. Its so simple I overlooked it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the `++` and `--` operators go by `1`.

You could create a class with the semantics you want, but you'll baffle future readers of your code.

Why fight the system?  Why not just say `x += 0.1;` etc.?